# Using IEnumerable methods, perform operation on first and second element of list, then second and third, etc, returning result as new IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have an IEnumerable and I want to get the difference between the first and second element, then the second and third, third and fourth, etc, and get an IEnumerable back with one fewer number of elements.

I know how to do this with foreach loops quite easily (skip the first element, and store a reference to the previous element), however I am curious if there is a way to do it in C# with IEnumerable Linq-like statements by default.

Comment: Check out `MoreLinq` - it has nice ways to handle this (likely `Lag` or `Lead`) that don't involve double enumeration (since the accepted answer here does double enumeration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly then you can use `Zip` with `.Skip(1)`:

```
var en = Enumerable.Range(0,5).ToList();
var result = en.Zip(en.Skip(1))
    .Select(t => t.First - t.Second)
    .ToList(); // results in list with {-1, -1, -1, -1}
```

Comment: I assume Zip handles the fact one IEnumerable is shorter than the other? Does it just end when the shortest one ends?

Comment: @TimMorris from the docs: "The method merges each element of the first sequence with an element that has the same index in the second sequence. If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them. For example, if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence will have only three elements."

Comment: This'll be useful in many more applications than what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @TimMorris was glad to help!